# I want to post a message in my console but getting type error

Tags: html, node.js, express

```
<input type="text" name ="firstName" class="form-control top" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
<input type="text" name ="lastName" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email" required>
```

The Node Express Code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();     

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(res, req) {
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var email = req.body.email;

    console.log(firstName, lastName, email);
})



app.listen(3000, function () {
 console.log("Server in port 3000")
})
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\app.js:15:30
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\User\desktop\learing\Newsletter-Sign\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

Comment: Your post and get methods seem to have different argument order for request and response.